# Reading from pipe using poll

Tags: c, unix, pipe

im trying to read data from pipe using poll, here is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE 128

int main(void){
    char buff[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    char *buf;
    int fd,ret,len;
    struct pollfd fdinfo[1];

    if((fd = open("/home/s/pipe", O_RDONLY)) == NULL) {
        printf("Error Opening File.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fdinfo[0].fd = fd;
    fdinfo[0].events = POLLIN|POLLPRI ;

    while(1){
        ret = poll(fdinfo,1,-1);
        if (ret < 0) printf("\n\r error");

        if ( ((fdinfo[0].revents&POLLIN) == POLLIN) || ((fdinfo[0].revents&POLLPRI) == POLLPRI) ){
            len = read(fdinfo[0].fd, buff, MAX_BUFF_SIZE);
            if (len > 0){
                buff[len] = 0;
                buf = (char *) malloc(len);
                memcpy(buf, buff, len);
                printf("\n read len %d\n %s",len, buf);
                free(buf);
             }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

It does not seems to work fine - after each properly data i got a lot of garbage in output, but i dont know where it comes frome. So im asking for help.

thx in advance

Comment: Don't use struct pollfd fdinfo[1];
Use struct pollfd *fdinfo, then dereference it. Easier to understand, and faster =).

Answer (score 1):

If there is at least `MAX_BUFF_SIZE` bytes available, `len` will be set to `MAX_BUFF_SIZE`, and `buff[len]` will write past the end of `buff`. After that, all bets are off. You can fix this by passing `MAX_BUFF_SIZE - 1` to `read()`.

However, more worryingly, you're not copying the `\0` in your `memcpy()` call, as the number of bytes *including* the `\0` is `len + 1`.

While we're at it:

- [don't cast the return](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) from `malloc()`
- check the return from `malloc()` isn't `NULL`
- if `poll()` errors, you're still checking the `revents` field, which won't be applicable any more
- your test `if ( ((fdinfo[0].revents&POLLIN) == POLLIN) || ((fdinfo[0].revents&POLLPRI) == POLLPRI) )` could better be written `if (fdinfo[0].revents & (POLLIN | POLLPRI))` but shouldn't be necessary anyway, as you've asked `poll()` to look for these two things only

Comment: +1 on all the corrections, except maybe the casting malloc() one. With modern standards, this shouldn't be a problem, and I see it as a good reminder of what kind of pointers you're dealing with.